# a bug in Java's stdlib SocksSocketImpl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, uri, ipv6

I've noticed a peculiar suppressed `URISyntaxException` in one of my Spring Boot apps during embedded Tomcat shutdown procedure via `TomcatWebServer#stop()` - and after debugging, found the source to be here:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/SocksSocketImpl.java#L306

(this happened for me on Eclipse Temurin 17.0.8.1, but I tried with other Java versions, and it looked mostly the same)

Basically, no matter how hard I stare at it, for an IPv6 (my use case) this code looks broken.

- `epoint.getHostString()` gives a valid IPv6, no braces (e.g. `fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862`)
- the following code detects IPv6 `epoint` and adds braces, `[fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862]`
- `ParseUtil.encodePath(host)` encodes that `host` to `%5bfd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862%5d` - this is problematic, because the hostname and port will be impossible to distinguish via URI parsing later, but shouldn't cause an exception by itself
- this is then concatenated with the schema/port and gives e.g. `socket://%5fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862%5d:55507` - even more problematic, since now it looks even more vexing both to human eye and probably to the `new URI` input parser as well,
- however, `new URI` c-tor constructs a URI with encoded hostname and port clumped together as `authority`, and `host == null` and `port == -1`

To work properly for IPv6-based hosts, `new URI` expects a *non-encoded* IPv6 address *with required literal braces*, i.e. `[fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862]`,

Simple replication case:

```
    URI uri = new URI("socket://[fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862]:55507");
    System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // [fd00:a89f:8b41:0:0:0:0:862] - OK
    uri = new URI("socket://%5fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862%5d:55507");
    System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // null - port is -1, everything got clumped in authority
    uri = new URI("socket://fd00:baba:babe:0:0:0:0:862:55507");
    System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // null - port is -1, everything got clumped in authority
```

I thought that having `host == null` should crash the SocksSocketImpl later on, but, surprisingly, in the only real place the `uri` is used, i.e. the call to `DefaultProxySelector#select(URI uri)` , I found an unrelated workaround... that is described explicitly as *not for this case* but allows the code to not fail! https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-10%2B24/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#L168 (i.e., this code *would* actually crash in normal situations, if not for a literally decades-old hacky workaround *for completely unrelated cases* - international domain names and domain names with underscore).

Am I missing something obvious, or is it a stacked bug in the stdlib itself (and thus should be reported upstream)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified as a bug and reported as https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8318130 - fixed in JDK 22 b21 via https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/16265/files